# What can be done about the [roslyn] and [roslyn-ctp] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm thinking that we need to merge [roslyn](/questions/tagged/roslyn) into [roslyn-ctp](/questions/tagged/roslyn-ctp).

Thoughts?

Comment: And when Roslyn is out of CTP?

Comment: @Oded its just a code name at this point - we would have the official product name

Comment: @Oded Then it'd be probably called "Visual Studio 2015 Compiler Services" or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

One is about the CTP, one is about the final release product.  They are two different things, and warrant two different tags.  If people are mis-tagging one as the other, or the tag wiki's don't clarify the difference, then it may warrant editing of the wikis/posts, but not a merging.